# async ( with non-async) function control flow clarification?

Tags: .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

( I've read a lot about async and I wonder what happens if there is a mix of async function call and non-async) and im talking about **THREAD pov** .

*( I know that mix should not be done , but im asking in order to understand the flow better)*

suppose I have(cube 1) function which calls async functions which calls asyc function.

*(please notice that cube 1 function is not async)*

Question :  when the control reaches (cube 3) `await Task.Delay(100);` --

what is really happening *as the control reaches* cube3 `await` ? does the control is back(and blocked) at the pink arrow (cube 1 ) or does the control is released and still awaits ( orange arrow)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When control reaches the `await` statement in `Cube3`, `Task.Delay()` is called and immediately returns a `Task` that will complete after the delay. The rest of `CalculateAnswer()` is refactored into a continuation that will run when the `Task` returned by `Delay()` completes, and `CalculateAnswer()` immediately returns a `Task<int>` that will complete when that continuation completes.

`CallCalculateAnswer()` awaits the `Task<int>` returned by `CalculateAnswer()`, so the same logic applies: the code running after the `await` (i.e. the `return` statement) is refactored into a continuation that will run when the `Task<int>` completes, and `CallCalculateAnswer()` proceeds to return its own `Task<int>`.

`StartChain()`, however, does not await the `Task<int>` produced by `CallCalculateAnswer()`, so no continuation is generated. Instead, it stores the task into a local variable and returns. Therefore, the orange arrow in your question is the right one.

Note that, in this specific case, since nothing is done with the `Task<int>` returned by `CallCalculateAnswer()` and it is only stored in a local variable, it becomes "forgotten" once `StartChain()` returns: the task will complete (or fail) some time in the future, but its result (the `int` it produces) will be lost.

**Update following comments:** The pink arrow in your question implies you're expecting `StartChain()` to block, waiting for the task returned by `CallCalculateAnswer()` to complete, because it is not `async` and does not `await` that task. This is not what happens, as the usual control flow semantics apply: the method has returned a task, so you get a reference to that task and nothing more.

If you want `StartChain()` to block, you can use [Task.Wait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx), [`Task<T>.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx), or similar on the task returned by `CallCalculateAnswer()`.

Comment: _When control reaches the await statement in Cube3, Task.Delay() is called and immediately returns_ -----returns to where ?

Comment: @Royi, to its caller, `CalculateAnswer()`, as usual.

Comment: Nope, to its immediate caller, like any function call. What makes you think control would skip an execution frame in that case?

Comment: I was thinking that the orange one will be the right one only if  startChain was async...

Comment: @Royi, it looks like you're thinking that calling an `async` method without awaiting the task it returns will block, waiting for that task to complete. That is not what happens, the control flow remains exactly the same as usual: the method has returned a task, so you get a reference to that task, nothing more, nothing less. If you want `StartChain()` to block, you can use [Task.Wait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx) or similar on the task returned by `CallCalculateAnswer()`.

Comment: you read my mind. that's what i was thinking actually. ( that if startChain is not async , so the control **waits at the pink arrow** ,after bubble up)

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph of this answer: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Does the system yields 2 tasks to await? ( both for cube 2 and 3 ? )

Comment: @Royi, I'm not sure to understand, can you clarify what you mean by "two tasks to await"?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi When the control reaches cubes 2 await , does it OPen a task to listen to , and also for the await of cube 3 ?

Comment: @Royi, a new `Task<int>` is returned from `CallCalculateAnswer()`, as the function awaits the `Task<int>` returned by `CalculateAnswer()`, yes.

Comment: Well I dont think so cuz [from here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) -- _Await examines that awaitable to see if it has already completed; if the awaitable has already completed, then the method just continues running (synchronously, just like a regular method)_ and also [becuase of my question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661428/async-stay-on-the-current-thread) - please look at B and D they are both on the same thread....(different thread from main but SAME thread BOTH)(im asking you just to be sure)

Comment: @Royi, well, if the awaited task has already completed, then `await` if indeed effectively ignored and the execution continues as if the keyword was not specified. In the general case, though, awaiting does mean the function returns.