# Read AsyncLocal value of a given thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Is there a way to read the value of an [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-5.0) value as another thread would see it?

Assume I have a thread executing and there I set a value. Now from another thread, with means like reflection or [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd), I would like to read the value of this `AsyncLocal` and get the value that would be returned if I would access it from the first thread. I want to observe what value is there in another async flow from the outside.

I know how `AsyncLocal` works and that it is not a value "fixed" to a thread. But I would like to know the value that a particular thread would get when reading the `AsyncLocal`.

**Important**

In the past I had a value in the `LogicalCallContext` on the `ExecutionContext` of a thread and was able to read it through reflection. So now I look for an alternative that works with `AsyncLocal`. The actual application of this was a diagnostics functionality.

**Update**

Looking at the code of `AsyncLocale` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/AsyncLocal.cs) made me thing there might be a way to retrieve this informaiton somehow. But when I tried I only saw that I would be able to read some AsyncLocales but not the one I was actually looking for. So I would be eager to know where this information is living in the CLR. Where is the data of the `AsyncLocale` living in the CLR?

Comment: `AsyncLocal` flows with the async flow, and async flow can flow across many threads - which is why `AsyncLocal` was invented in the first place. So it doesn't make sense to ask for the AsyncLocal *of a thread*. Are you actually talking about *threads* (because [async is not about threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17661428/11683)) or *tasks in flight*?

Comment: Yes I know. I want to read data from the current async flow that a given thread is executing.